# mongodb remove elements from array

Tags: mongodb

Let say I have Object:

```
{
    "id":"5a759fb9b953782e38366032",
    "question":"change 111",
    "answer":[
        {"_id":"5a759fb9b953782e38366034","a":"new 123"},
        {"_id":"5a75fccdc678791900c87be9","a":"www"},
        {"_id":"5a75fccdc678791900c87be9","a":"ssss"}
        ]
}
```

I want to remove elements from array based on _id. I did try

```
let bulk = Quiz.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({ _id: new ObjectID('5a759fb9b953782e38366034') }).remove();
bulk.find({ _id: new ObjectID('5a75fccdc678791900c87be9') }).remove();
bulk.execute();
```

No results.

I try

```
let bulk = Quiz.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({ _id: new ObjectID('5a759fb9b953782e38366032') }).update({$pull:{answer:{_id:'5a759fb9b953782e38366034'}}})
bulk.execute();
```

no results

Comment: "`$pull:{answer:{_id:'5a759fb9b953782e38366034'}}`" - this won't work if your id is actually an ObjectId.

Comment: So how can i change that, some fake Id to answer element ?. If so what's the point of objectId ?
I change to bulk.find({ _id: new ObjectID('5a759fb9b953782e38366032') }).update({$pull:{"a":'new 123'}});
no results

this works:
bulk.find({ _id: new ObjectID('5a7d9a9940459b43d8fe32c6') }).update({$pull:{answer:{_id: new ObjectID('5a759fb9b953782e38366034')}}});

Comment: "this works" - See, told ya.